# Wording on SOFU About page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tour

The About page on SOFU currently says:

> You can register if you want to
>   collect karma and win valuable flair
>   that will appear next to your name,
>   but otherwise, it's just free. And
>   fast. Very, very fast.

Shouldn't *karma* be replaced with *reputation*?

Comment: This was overlooked when SO got ported from [CNPROG](http://cnprog.com/).

Comment: Shouldn't 'valuable' be replaced with an empty string?

Comment: @JonS: Probably `flair` with `badges` too.

Comment: Am I the only one who keeps mis-reading SOFU as STFU? For a second there I thought there was a special page being shown to annoying users.

Answer (score 4):

No, because we are using the terms generically here "flair" and "karma" in the abstract sense to refer to the concepts.

Not literally.

Comment: what is the "abstract concept" of "flair"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+flair