# Is it "rep" or "karma"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tour

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wording on SOFU about page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49226/wording-on-sofu-about-page)

I have noticed recently when looking at the "original trilogy"s' about pages, they use the word "karma" instead of rep. I'm not sure whether that is still supposed to be like that, but over the time that I have been a member here (about a year) I have never heard the term "karma" used.

Also, I wasn't sure about the "valuable flair" part either. Is that referring to badges?

Should "Karma" be changed to "Reputation" instead? and should "flair" be changed to "badges"?

[image: Stackoverflow]

[image: Superuser]

[image: Serverfault]

Comment: At one point there was a thread on alternate names for the stuff. Can't find it anymore. Ah, well.

Comment: +1 for **reading** the about page. ;)

Comment: So What? Who cares? Isn't this just like a dozen other websites?

Answer (score 6):

"Valuable flair," really just "flair," is the image/HTML page that can be found here on your profile page:

[image: Flair on profile page]

Mine looks like this:

[image: My valuable flair]

As for the "karma," it doesn't necessarily apply to rep I suppose, but if it does it should be changed. (I don't like it when people call it karma, either...)

Answer (score 2):

Well, [according to Jeff](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/) this is reputation, where *karma* is "Slashdot/Reddit parlance":

> The trick here is that downvotes are mostly informational. The cost of a downvote to the users’ reputation **(or karma in Slashdot/Reddit parlance)** is quite low. It would take a whopping 5 downvotes to equal the effect of a single upvote. And, on top of that, downvotes cost you a tiny bit of reputation...

I don't think it should stick in the official About pages of the sites.

Comment: In some sense, the concept of my "reputation" decreasing for downvoting a wrong answer seems wrong... I have no qualms about my "karma" decreasing though.

Comment: @yoda still, personally "karma" does not sound professional enough to officially describe this.

Comment: I agree fully... I also understand (and agree) why there's a -1 penalty. Just that seeing it written out (that my "reputation" decreases) and reading it back to myself feels weird :)

Comment: @yoda well I for one feel it rather fair when I [receive -1 for downvoting the answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2opbY.jpg "BTDTGTTS"). Reputation wise I consider these drops an indication of certain laziness, of _choosing the easy way_ instead of investing my own effort into improving the answer

Comment: @gnat I fully agree with that and certainly don't shy away from downvoting no matter how much I lose. I just meant terminology wise... it just feels odd to say that you're some `δx` less reputable just because you told someone they're wrong :)